# Store some data on server to access without a db

Tags: java, php, server

I want to store a little bit of data on my server that can be accessed easily by anyone. It's for a game I am making and I want to store a few things such as:

- Game version (String)
- Description (Long String)
- News (Array of Strings)
- Changelog (Array of Strings)
  etc...

I figured that making a whole database and table for this would be overkill. I would like to be able to access the information using various types of media but I at least ant it to work with PHP (web) and Java (Desktop and android). Also the data will be updated and inputted manually by only me but readable publicly so that other websites can use it if they choose. What would I use for this kind of thing?

Extra: I might eventually want to input data manually. Things such as "Players Joined" would be managed by my server and would increment it automatically.So if it can do that too that would be great.

Comment: store it in file and read it

Comment: How would you get the file, would it be in the apache folder?

Comment: you mean read the file in php?
yes it will be inside root folder

Comment: Is that the most efficient way? There has to be some sort of program that can do this using queries or something that would be a lot faster.

Comment: you can use `sqlite`

Comment: `file_put_contents($file, json_encode($array))` and `$array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true)`

Comment: Well technically using a database IS using a file... so using a small database for it versus using a file (json or xml most likely) won't make much of a difference. The database is likely a better option. You have to store the data somewhere. Both options are pretty efficient.

Comment: you will have two option either save it in DB or Flat File, its upto you

Comment: Hmm I looked into JSON. Looks like that might be the solution. Is there a way to store simple data on a db though (Without making tables)? I could probably use tables for news but for things like Game version, it would be overkill. Maybe I'll think of something. Thank you for getting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use a Database and access the data with MySQL. I already have one for my game so it is a good choice because of that (this means I won't be creating a whole database just for this). I will create a table that will store this data and the table will only have 1 row (ID = 0). I will access it by selecting the row with ID = 0. I will have to create other tables with news and changelogs too.

If you have a similar question to mine, check this out:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/storing-data-with-php-flat-file-or-database.html

It provided some useful advice. Also look into JSON or XML and SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). It can run as an embedded database (just include a jar, no extra installation, etc.), is very solid and you can get up and running very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for this but as for my case, I have already decided to use something different. Perhaps this will be useful to someone who comes along.